# sum values grouped by timestamp

Tags: flux-influxdb

I'm new to FluxQL and was wondering if I can sum values regardless of tag value grouped by a timestamp.

I have something like this:

| _time | _measurement | collection | _value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | some_measurement | foo | 1 |
| 0001 | some_measurement | bar | 12 |
| 0002 | some_measurement | foo | 8 |
| 0002 | some_measurement | bar | 4 |

I want to sum values by time so in the end I would need something like:

| _time | _measurement | collection | _value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | some_measurement | total | 13 |
| 0002 | some_measurement | total | 12 |

Have in mind that I may have ~100 different collection tag values.

Comment: Do you want to use Flux or InfluxQL ? They are [different languages](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/flux/flux-vs-influxql/)

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I would like to use Flux @kaios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum values by time, you need to [group them](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/flux/stdlib/built-in/transformations/group/)

```
|> group(columns: ["_time", "_measurement"])
```

You can add any column you want to keep.

The measurements will not always be sorted by time, so if you need that, just add:

```
|> sort(columns: ["_time"])
```